# How to correctly create and stop kthreads?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, multithreading

I wrote the following kernel module:

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/semaphore.h>
#include <linux/spinlock.h> 
     
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Madhuparna Bhowmik <madhuparnabhowmik04@gmail.com>");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Example for using threads");
    
static struct task_struct *t1;
static struct task_struct *t2;

static int t1_f(void *unused)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Current value in t1 is %d",7);
    do_exit(0);
    return 0;
}

static int t2_f(void *unused)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Current value in t2 is %d",8);
    do_exit(0);
    return 0;
}

static int __init start_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Thread Creating...\n");
    t1 = kthread_run(t1_f,NULL,"mythread1");
    t2 = kthread_run(t2_f,NULL,"mythread2");
    
    return 0;
}

static void __exit end_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Cleaning Up...\n");
}

    
module_init(start_init)
module_exit(end_exit)
```

When I load this module using :

```
sudo insmod test1.ko
```

Checking kern.log file gives the following result:

```
Oct  8 00:24:13 madhuparna-VirtualBox kernel: [ 5752.075918] Thread creating ...

Oct  8 00:24:13 madhuparna-VirtualBox kernel: [ 5752.076009] Current value in t1 is 7
```

There is no log for thread2 yet.

After I execute :

```
sudo rmmod test1.ko
```

The log is:

```
Oct  8 00:24:13 madhuparna-VirtualBox kernel: [ 5752.075918] Thread creating ...
Oct  8 00:24:13 madhuparna-VirtualBox kernel: [ 5752.076009] Current value in t1 is 7
Oct  8 00:24:54 madhuparna-VirtualBox kernel: [ 5752.077780] Current value in t2 is 8
Oct  8 00:24:54 madhuparna-VirtualBox kernel: [ 5793.099359] Cleaning up ...
```

So, can someone please explain that why does thread 2 does not start running until I use rmmod and unload the kernel? Why is only thread1 executing?

Answer (score 4):

You need to append a newline to the end of `printk()`. It seems that `printk()` without newline will not be flushed into `dmesg` until another `printk()` without `KERN_CONT`.

```c
printk(KERN_INFO "Current value in t1 is %d\n",7);
printk(KERN_INFO "Current value in t2 is %d\n",8);
```

As for how to correctly create and stop kthreads, here is a sample code I wrote. Hope it will help.
https://gist.github.com/seekstar/4bdef2a775383d417e265317832e44ed

The reason of using `struct completion entered`:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65987208/kthread-stopped-without-running

You could cancel a thread in this manner:

```c
t1 = kthread_create(func, &para1, "t1");
// Oops, something went wrong(such as failing to create another kthread)
ret = kthread_stop(t1);
```

In this way, `func` will not be executed, and `ktheard_stop` will return `-EINTR`.