# Why do_exit() undefined?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, c

I was building a kernel module for trying `kthreads`. A thread function after doing its works exits by calling do_exit(0).

But when I am trying to compile the module, it is showing the error that `modpost: do_exit undefined`.
I have learnt that each `kthread` should exit by calling `do_exit()`. But it is giving me error while doing so.

Comment: this may help ... https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~cop4610t/lectures/project2/kthreads/kthreads.pdf

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/545587/how-to-correctly-create-and-stop-kthreads